# (ring homomorphisms $k[X] / (f(X)) → R)$ ⇆ $\{x \in k | f(x) = 0 \}$ one-to-one correspondence

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I want to prove that there is a bijection from the set of $k$-algebra homomorphisms $k[X] / (f(X))\rightarrow R$ to $V(f) = \{x \in k | f(x) = 0 \}$, where $k$ is a field.

What should I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you don't want $R$ to be a $k$-algebra, and your bijection to be between $k$-algebra morphisms $k[X]/\langle f(X) \rangle \to R$ and $\{x \in R \mid f(x) = 0\}$?

Comment: The slide I read is not strict, hence a requirement for R didn't writed.
If it's alright with you, I want to be a bijection between k-algebra morphisms $k[X]/⟨f(X)⟩→R$ and $\{x∈R∣f(x)=0\}$!